# Advanced Nesting (Hierarchy) in SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework, hierarchical-data

I have read a lot of posts already on Hierarchy, Trees, composed keys and a lot more of issues in SQL but i can't find the info i need. I'm working with EF6 and SQL, C#.

**The Case:**
[image]

Let's Say that i have the following model. So the Application can be on each of these platforms  (Or only on one or two of them. Application would be a base class and the OSX and windows and PlatformX would inherted him, if speaking from code.). But the Application can have for each platform reviews and a review may apply for multiple platforms. So i'm trying to model a database that doesn't need to separate the reviews in 3 different tables.

Has somebody got a good example on how to model this in the sql database? Or isn't this possible?

Some required queries would be: 
 - Get all specified Types(OSX, winodws etc..) of an application?
 - Get all reviews of an application Type.
 - Get all Reviews of an application.
 - Get all applications by a review. (And could i then find out which type it is?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand `Application` is a base entity for `OSX`, `Windows` and `PlatformX`.

My first remark is, if your `~Value` fields are platform specific fields for each component, like

```
-----------  ------------------
| Windows |  | OSX            |
-----------  -----------------|
| WinApi  |  | SupportsMobile |
| TempDir |  | WrittenLang    |
-----------  ------------------
```

Then you probably would like to make one table for `Application` and its primary key would be an identity field. Other entities are suggested to be separate tables, but would use the `Application`'s primary key as their own, i.e. one to one relationship.

If the above is not true for your case and your tables are going to have `Value1`, `Value2` and `Value3` and the same data type, then I strongly recommend you to merge all classes into one table and add integer flag `Platform`. So you'll end up with only two tables which really simplify your work and will not truncate on functionality.

However resolution of your case with Review is the same for both cases. I advice you to connect `Application` table to `Review` table, this will save you a lot of time.

All your query questions: Yes you can do all of them.

**EDIT**

Ok, let me show you my vision.

Application (**ApplicationId**, Name, Price, Namespace) 
OSX (**ApplicationId***, OSXValue1, OSXValue2, OSXValue3) 
Windows (**ApplicationId***, WindowsValue1, WindowsValue2, WindowsValue3) 
PlatformX (**ApplicationId***, XValue1, XValue2, XValue3) 
Review (**ReviewId**, ApplicationId*, FullName, ReviewText)

**NB** Please note that I used PascalCase for field names. This is a good convention for working with EF, as fields will map to the property names (by convention) and does not break the overall naming in you .NET application.

Here `ApplicationId` in the `Application` table is an identity field and is a primary key. In tables `OSX`, `Windows` and `PlatformX` you define `ApplicationId` field, define it as a primary key, and foreign key referencing `ApplicationId` field in `Application` table for each of them.

This is the way you store it.

As of Entity framework
Define your classes as follows

```
public class Application {
    private ICollection<Review> _Reviews;
    public Int64 ApplicationId { get; set; }
    /*Other fields*/
    public Windows Windows { get; set; }
    public Osx Osx { get; set; }
    public PlatformX PlatformX { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Review> Reviews {
        get { return _Reviews = _Reviews ?? new List<Review>(); }
        set { _Reviews = value; }
    }
}

public class Osx {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [ForeignKey("Application")]
    public Int64 ApplicationId { get; set; }
    /*Other fields*/
    public Application Application { get; set; }
}

public class PlatformX {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [ForeignKey("Application")]
    public Int64 ApplicationId { get; set; }
    /*Other fields*/
    public Application Application { get; set; }
}

public class Windows {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [ForeignKey("Application")]
    public Int64 ApplicationId { get; set; }
    /*Other fields*/
    public Application Application { get; set; }
}

public class Review {
    public Int64 ReviewId { get; set; }
    public Int64 ApplicationId { get; set; }
    /*Other fields*/
    //Convention will catch up the ApplicationId field automatically
    public Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

Here you define some non obvious features by data annotations, e.g. the keys that does not match convention TableName + 'Id'. Further, you indicate that `ApplicationId` fields are not autogenerated using `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute`.

The following query gets the list of all applications with type `Osx` and `Windows`

```
var context = new DemoContext();
var res = context.Osx.Select(x=>x.Application).Union(context.Windows.Select(x=> x.Application));
```

This is a query of applications by review with its types

```
var res2 = context.Reviews.Select(x => new {
    x.Application,
    IsOsx = x.Application.Osx != null,
    IsWindows = x.Application.Windows != null,
    IsPlatformX = x.Application.PlatformX != null
});
```

You can find out the types according to the Boolean values in the object.

Comment: First of all, yes you understood me well. Windows an OSx etc.. will have different fields and are platform specific. Second, you say to connect the Reviews to an application table? but how do you know in that case, to which applicationtypes(windows,osx,etc..) the review belongs? Because Windows may have 2 reviews from which one also belongs to OSX. Could you collaborate a bit more on that part?

Comment: And another big question is, will this all work with EF6. or isn't EF6 capable of doing this?

Comment: Generally speaking EF6 immensely widens developer's capabilities. You have to dig a little bit about `IQueryable<T>` and expressions and have some practice to figure out the best approaches. LINQ is wonderful and you have to explore it.

Comment: Really i love your example and your commitment :) you helped me a lot already! But i keeping one doubt. A.t.m. a Review belongs to all platforms made. My intention was to make this variable. the fact that an application is available on Windows and OSX, won't say the review belongs to all of them . But should also be able to only belong to OSX.This would be solveable by some boolean fields in the Review...But is there no easier way?

Comment: There are many solutions, you can add a field to the review with integer indicator, or you can review table for each platform type, you can have ReviewevedApplicationId **for each** table. But never ever use one field for all tables.